# Module imported by name in Python 3 can't find modules in the original script's path

Tags: python, module, path, python-import, python-3.7

I am successfully importing a module by name in Python 3.7 as is recomeded in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly):

```
import importlib.util
import sys

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

However when I do this, some of the import statements of that module will fail.

How can I share the context and module paths of my running python program with this freshly loaded module so that all imports succeed?

The error it produces is `No module named 'XXXX'` where XXXX is available from main script.

Comment: were you able to solve this? I am also facing similar issue